# JQ only return matching child results with parent

Tags: json, parent-child, jq

I am trying to get JSON data where a child key match exists, but I want to exclude data from other child elements that don't match. An example would use the following JSON, trying to return `id` from the parent and `quantity` from the child, where the child `catalog_object_id` "VJXWCBDL":

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "IKF7HPIP",
        "quantity": "5"
      },
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "VJXWCBDL",
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "JXOACUE",
        "quantity": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "VJXWCBDL",
        "quantity": "2"
      },
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "RGQMKXKL",
        "quantity": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "d",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "catalog_object_id": "VJXWCBDL",
        "quantity": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output that I'm looking for is:

```
[
  "a",
  "1"
]
[
  "c",
  "2"
]
[
  "d",
  "4"
]
```

When I use `select` based on the object id, it returns the values for the other ids as well. I'm sure there's an easy answer to this that I haven't been able to figure out.

```
jq '.[] | select ( .line_items[].catalog_object_id == "VJXWCBDL" ) | [ .id, .line_items[].quantity ]' test.json
```

What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```sh
jq --arg q "VJXWCBDL" '
  .[] | [.id] + (.line_items[] | select(.catalog_object_id == $q) | [.quantity])
' test.json
```

```json
[
  "a",
  "1"
]
[
  "c",
  "2"
]
[
  "d",
  "4"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ezx9dlo8NM)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why this is hard to get my head around, but I see that .id is put into a list with the matching child quantity.

Comment: You need to grab `.id` before you leave the scope by descending into iteration. I chose to add two one-element-arrays here, but you also could have stored the value in a variable using `.id as $id` to then employ it later when constructing the final array at once `[$id, .quantity]`.